# Using EDSDK 2.14 with Rebel T3i - Raw + JPEG

Tags: edsdk

I last used SDK 2.9 with EOS 5D Mark II camera, and all was working well.  Now I have updated to use SDK 2.14 with EOS Rebel T3i camera.  I have 3 issues:

1) I set the mode to return both RAW and JPEG -- but this does not work at all - my code hangs/crashes -- if I set to RAW only, then it works.  Does Rebel T3i not support RAW + JPEG ?

2) I used to be able to set for different size RAW images (RAW1, RAW2) -- so in my application the user could select which resolution he wants.  But now with Rebel T3i, regardless of the mode setting the image I get back is always 25 MB

3) The RAW image I get back is 8-bits-per-pixel -- I used to be able to get 16-bpp with the 5D Mark II -- is there a way with the Rebel T3i?

Answer (score 0):

1) I would just be guessing
2)  You need to set this:

```
uint setError = EDSDK.EdsSetPropertyData(camera, EDSDK.PropID_ImageQuality, 0, sizeof(UInt32), EDSDK.ImageQuality.EdsImageQuality_MR);
```

Where 'camera' is a pointer handle.  The EDSDK 2.14 has a new EdsImageQuality Enum.
Not sure how to help with 3.